# Alertify JS- Change button text on prompt dialog

Tags: jquery, alertifyjs

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
    alertify.prompt("Please enter note/remarks for this Form:", function (e, value) {
        $("#alertify-ok").val('Submit Form'); //change button text
            if (e) {
                alertify.success("Form has been submitted");
            } else {
                alertify.error("Your form is not submitted");
            }
        });
```

HTML for alertify prompt dialog

```
<button id="alertify-ok" class="alertify-button alertify-button-ok" type="submit">
    OK
</button>
```

The prompt appears when user clicks on submit button. Tried changing button text using below but its not working

```
$("#alertify-ok").val('Submit Form'); //change button text
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/72/)- where I need to change the default `OK` button text to something else

How could I change the button text to `Submit Form` instead of default `OK` ?

Comment: i added some answer, i dont have account to edit fiddle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<button>` has `innerText` property and does not have `value`. Use `.text()`

```
$("#alertify-ok").text('Submit Form'); //change button text
```

Use **[`.set('labels')`](http://alertifyjs.com/prompt/labels.html)** option to change default text.

```
alertify.prompt('Please enter your comments', 'some value', 
    function(evt, value){ alertify.message('You entered: ' + value);}
).set('labels', {ok:'Submit', cancel:'Cancel'});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/76/)**

Comment: The text changes when I click on `OK` for prompt dialog. The prompt dialog still has default button value. The value will change but on which event ?

Comment: Pls see fiddle where I need to change default button text  http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/72/

Comment: Their site says so. Everything must be ideally backward compatible. Check with your version.

Comment: snippet  that worked for older version - `alertify.set({ labels: {
                                    ok     : "Submit Form",
                                    cancel : "Cancel"
                                } });`

Answer (score 1):

Found this : [alertify](http://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html)

```
alertify.prompt('Please enter your comments', 'some value', 
    function(evt, value){ alertify.message('You entered: ' + value);}
).set('labels', {ok:'Submit Form', cancel:'New Cancel'});
```